# How can I use drag-over in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with size 500x250px. When you drag any element onto it, its border should change color. I tried to achieve this effect using drag-over in CSS, but I could not get it to work.

```css
#element{
   width:500px;
   height:250px;
   border:2px solid orange;
}

#element::drag-over{
  border-color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

A solution in jQuery:

```js
$('input[type="file"]').on('dragover', function(){
     $(this).addClass('drag-over'); 
   }).on('drop', function (e) {   
      $(this).removeClass('drag-over'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element">
    <input type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: this is a non-standard feature, so it may not work in all the cases https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A-moz-drag-over

Comment: is there any solution for this in with jquery?

Comment: you need to prove full code then ... with the code that make the drag/drop so we can suggest a solution based on it

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jQuery UI library, you can use drag events, easily. Look in the inspector as you drag over an item and it will add a class of `ui-droppable-hover`. Then on the originalClass in the CSS, set a `transition: 200ms ease-in-out` or similar; now add a new CSS selector of `.originalClass.ui-droppable-hover { make your CSS changes }`. The changes will be smooth on dragover and dragout